# ruby string cutting

Tags: ruby, regex, string, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an equivalent of Array#find_index for the last index in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553947/is-there-an-equivalent-of-arrayfind-index-for-the-last-index-in-ruby)

I have a string

```
story = "Everything before the word irrelevent is irrelevent. Everything after it is relevent"
```

I want to remove everything before(and including ) the last occurence of "irrelevent". How do i do this in ruby.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553947/is-there-an-equivalent-of-arrayfind-index-for-the-last-index-in-ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
story.gsub /.*irrelevent/, ''
```

Also, you misspelled irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
story.split(/\birrelevent\b/).last
```

Comment: and you can use `story.split(/irrelevent/).last` to remove dot

Comment: `story.split(/\birrelevent\b[^\w\d]+/).last`

Answer (score 1):

Regexp worked: http://rubular.com/r/xj9NB7Hekq

In Ruby: `story[/irrelevent(?:(?!irrelevent).)*$/]`

Comment: But does not remove last occurrence. But it's trivial.